# Linking static library from Xcode into Lazarus app fails on architecture mismatch

Tags: xcode, linker, archive, lazarus, mismatch

Much research here and in-depth exploration via Google links, to no avail.

I've made a simple, one function, static C library with OSX Xcode (5) which I'm trying to link into a Lazarus app, basically to port the Xcode function from Xcode to Lazarus.

Xcode builds the static library alright, and I have what seems to be the proper linkage code in the Lazarus app, as follows:

```
type
byteptr = ^byte;

const
libname = 'libLORaudio.a';

function LORaudioPlay (fd : longint; audio : byteptr): Integer;
     cdecl; external libname;

r := LORaudioPlay(e, z);
```

All of that compiles just fine, but the build fails with the following messages:

```
Id: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
Id: Warning: ignoring file libLORaudio.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): libLORaudio.a

(and it goes on to say the function is undefined, of course, since it ignored the library that supplies it.)
```

My problem could be solved in either of two ways, neither of which have I found sufficient information on, online nor within Xcode or Lazarus.

One solution would be to get Xcode to produce the static library with the architecture expected by Lazarus. I have tried the various options for setting the build architectures in Xcode mentioned in other answers here to similar questions, but it seems I haven't done them correctly because none of them worked for me.

The other solution would be to get Lazarus to accept the architecture produced by Xcode. The Laz.y documentation is not helpful in this regard.

Any suggestions I could try? Thanks so very much for your consideration.

Comment: I would guess that you have compiled your library for architecture different from the architecture of the Lazarus/FPC (i386 as mentioned in the warning text). Try to set 32-bit architecture in the build mode of your library.

Comment: @Abelisto Definitely an architecture mismatch. I tried multiple ways to get Xcode to accept a 32 bit architecture specification, but it accepted only "i386 x86_64" which it was originally. Is there some back door to the build settings?

Comment: Not sure, I am not familiar with OS X. But you can also try to change target OS and processor in the Lazarus project options ("Config and target" page). [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freepascal/files/Mac%20OS%20X/2.6.4/) you can download and install appropriate FPC. You need `fpc-2.6.4.intel-ppc64-macosx.dmg` as I understand (check version, it must be same with already installed FPC).

Answer (score 2):

So eventually, I scrounged around with Finder and found where (see below) I had built both the x86_64 and the i386 object files in separate attempts to solve the problem. This was done by changing the build settings for Architectures to 'i386'. Subsequent re-builds for 'x86_64' didn't remove the i386 object info from earlier.

Then I copied the i386 object file into the folder containing the Lazarus project (it was necessary to make the copy with the alt-option dragging method, as copy then paste didn't work).

There, I ran ar on it in Terminal, as: 'ar -r -s  libname.a  name.o' to build the static lib from the object.

Lazarus now handles the library as desired. (This of course, revealed some other buggy situations to be dealt with, but hey, progress happens.)

Xcode had put both versions of the object in a folder. Find these products from Xcode by right-clicking on the product mentioned in the project navigator and choose 'show in finder'. You can do this for whichever architecture you currently have; both lead to the same build folders.  From there work your way back up thru the containing folders until you spot Build. Open that and work your way forward among the contained folders until you get to Objects-normal. In there you'll find folders for i386 and x86_64. Each of those folders contains the corresponding object file as name.o among other product related files.